# Batch Replace of !-sign

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to remove the character `!` in a variable.

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 
set filename=!filename:!=_!
```

I have already tried to escape it with `^` but this did not work.

```
Set filename=!filename:^!=_!
```

How can I get rid of the !-sign in the variable?

Comment: is it part of loop or if condition?Cant you disable the delayed expansion?

Comment: Yes, it is part of a loop. the delayed expansion is needed.

Comment: Do you can show your loop and where the filename is _produced_

Answer (score 4):

You cannot replace `%` when using normal expansion. You must use delayed expansion insntead: `!var:%%=_!`

Likewise, you cannot replace `!` when using delayed expansion. You must use normal expansion instead: `%var:!=_%`.

But that can be a problem if your variable may contain a mixture of poison characters like `^`, `&`, `|`, `>`, `<` as well as quotes. For example, there is no single step way to replace `!` within the following string: `"This & that" & the other thing!`

The trick is to do the replacement in stages, using mostly delayed expansion, with one replacement using normal expansion.

1) Delayed expansion - convert `"` into `""`

2) Normal expansion - convert `!` into `replacement`. Because all quotes are doubled, outer quotes around expansion now guaranteed to protect all poison characters

3) Delayed expansion - convert `""` back into `"`

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "var="This ^& that" & the other thing^!"
echo before: !var!

set "var=!var:"=""!"
set "var=%var:!=_%"
set "var=!var:""="!"

echo  after: !var!
```

-- Output --

```
before: "This & that" & the other thing!
 after: "This & that" & the other thing_
```

But you are dealing with file names, which can make the problem simpler :-)

File names can contain the poison characters `&` and `^`, but they cannot contain quotes. You can put quotes anywhere within a file name (or path), and they will protect poison characters. But the quotes are removed by the OS when it stores or looks for files on disk.

So I generally make sure that my file name and path variables do not contain quotes. Then it is safe to simply use:

```
set "filename=%filename:!=_%"
```

**Oops - I only just now read the question comments, and see that this is within a loop!**

The fact that the substitution occurs within a loop complicates things, since normal expansion will not see values that are defined within the loop.

Note that delayed expansion must be off when a FOR variable is expanded, otherwise it will corrupt `!` within the file name.

The simplest solution is to use CALL to get an extra round of expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (*) do (
  set "file=%%F"
  call set "file=%%file:!=_%%"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  echo file=!file!
  endlocal
)
```

If you are doing other manipulations that require delayed expansion, then the `!` will need to be escaped within the normal expansion replacement expression because delayed expansion occurs before CALL. (thanks jeb).

Here is an example that eliminates `^` and `&` as well.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (*) do (
  set "file=%%F"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "file=!file:^=_!"
  set "file=!file:&= and !"
  call set "file=%%file:^!=_%%"
  echo file=!file!
  endlocal
)
```

Although I could have simply enabled delayed expansion *after* I have already removed `!`. Then the escape would not be needed.

Comment: Some constructive critism: `call set "file=%%file:!=_%%"` will not work in your sample, as the `!` will be removed before the percent expansion is done, so the percent expansion fails as `%file:=_%` isn't valid. You **don't need** a subroutine, as the CALL-phase never sees any carets. The solution is `call set "file=%%file:^!=_%%"

Comment: @jeb - Thanks jeb - your are correct on both counts (of course). I forgot about the escape issue, (and obviously didn't test), and didn't think the caret doubling through properly. I've edited my answer to address both your points.

Answer (score 2):

the only that pops up at my mind at the moment is subroutine and tunneling:

```
@echo off

set "line=!---!asd!asd!"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo !line!
    call :subr "!line!" line
    echo !line!
endlocal
exit /b %errorlevel%

:subr
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
    set "string=%~1"
    set "res=%string:!=$%"
endlocal && (
    set "%~2=%res%"
)
```

just define the subroutine like this at the end of your script and call it in the for loop

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of a subroutine. `set "line=%line:!=$%"` while delayed expansion is enabled would work just as well, and it is so much simpler. Even if you wanted to temporarily disable delayed expansion, there is no need to involve a subroutine. But disabling delayed expansion is totally unnecessary.

Comment: @dbenham - the OP says this is part of FOR loop - so the line wont work in this case.This is rather a demo how the subroutine can be used - as the whole piece of code is not posted I needed my own example.

Comment: Oh snap. I missed the comments. You are perfectly correct - a CALL is needed.

Comment: This will fail in the unlikely event that the string contains `^` because of CALL caret doubling. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30832412/1012053)